# ¿Por qué no es posible llamar a un método no estático desde uno estático?

Tags: c#

¿Por qué no es posible llamar a un método NO estático desde uno SÍ estático, estando los dos métodos dentro de la misma clase?

¿Cuál es la razón? ¿De que manera podría hacerlo?

```
private void NoEstatico()
{
    NoEstatico();
    SiEstatico();
}

static private void SiEstatico()
{
    NoEstatico(); <-------- ERROR
    SiEstatico();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buenas Edulon,

La respuesta a tu pregunta es que las **funciones/clases [estáticas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)** no se pueden instanciar, mientras que las **no estáticas** requiere que las instancies para poder llamarlas.

Dicho esto te voy a mostrar un ejemplo de cada una y como poder llamar una función no estática en una que si lo es:

```
public class Class1
{
    private void NoEstatico()
    {
        SiEstatico(); //Ya estas en la clase Class1, así que no hace falta llamar a la clase y despues la función estática.
    }

    static private void SiEstatico()
    {
        Class1 cls1 = new Class1(); //Instanciamos la clase contenedora de NoEstatico() para poder llamarlo
        cls1.NoEstatico();
    }
}
```

Cuando quieres llamar des de otra clase una función estática deberás poner siempre **nombre_clase.nombre_función** (`Class1.SiEstatico();`) mientras que dentro de la misma clase no hace falta que pongas el nombre de la clase para llamar la función estática.

Comment: Tenia claro eso, lo que no sabia es que aun estando el metodo dentro de la misma clase debia igualmente instanciar un objeto de clase.
Gracias a los dos

Answer (score 3):

Un método no estático puede hacer referencia a propiedades o campos **de instancia**, por lo que al ser llamado desde un método estático, a cual de las instancias se referiría?

Ejemplo:

Dada la siguiente clase y asumiendo (incorrectamente) que no es error de sintaxis y compila.

```
public class Coordenada
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public string NombreNoEstatico() => $"({X}, {Y})";

    public static void ImprimirNombreEstatico() => Console.WriteLine(NombreNoEstatico()); // Este método no puede ser estático ya que llama a un método de instancia
}
```

¿El sgte código que debería imprimir?

```
var c1 = new Coordenada { X = 1, Y = 1 };
var c2 = new Coordenada { X = 2, Y = 2 };

Coordenada.ImprimirNombreEstatico();
```

Como verás `ImprimirNombreEstatico()` no puede llamar a `NombreEstatico()` porque éste hace referencia a `X` y a `Y` que no existen a nivel de la **clase** sino a nivel de la **instancia de la clase**